# DFT algorithm output meanning

Tags: fft, dft

[image]

The result of calculating the amplitude of the audio through the DFT algorithm above is
It came out as below.

```
4.8829615116119385 + 8.486573384979136e-11i
-5.105256495330224e-13 + 2.5007562752359103e-12i
-2.6504666517102038e-12 + 4.1986813331673645e-12i
5.8794774604464806e-12 + 2.1755991105876227e-11i
-1.6939658009640368e-11 - 3.9704658831574147e-11i
```

I don't understand exactly the meaning of the above results.

1. Data center of gravity coordinates on a complex plane.
2. The data center of gravity coordinates on the complex plane and the distance from the origin.

Please tell us what the above result means between the most of the two meanings.

Comment: Neither 1. nor 2. does have any speciific meaning. Why would the "data center" (which is really just the sum of all complex numbers) have a meaning?

Answer (score 2):

The magnitude of these complex numbers tells the amplitude of sinusoids frequency and the phase of these complex numbers tells the phase shift of each sinusoids that needs to be applied to recreate the original signal.